# what is the easiest way to implement page routing into asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms-routing

I need to know the easiest way to implement asp.net 3.5 URL routing as I can't upgrade my solution now to asp.net 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is part of ASP.NET since 3.5 SP1.

Take a look at this article: [Routing with ASP.NET Web Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx).

Comment: +0 for having the same answer as Tim, +1 for adding the Web Forms Routing Reference.

Answer (score 1):

the routing is a part of 3.5 SP1

Comment: +1 - just make sure you have 3.5 SP1 and you can implement routing out of the box.